# Array result solutin

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array

```
$data = array( 
0 => array( "id" => 2, "status" => 1), 
1 => array( "name" => "you", "class" => "expert"),
);
```

I want result

```
$result = array(
"id" => 2,
"status" => 1,
"name" => "you",
"class" => "expert"
);
```

How to solved it ?

Comment: What did you try? SO is not a place where you throw your problem and wait for others to solve it. Have you read the list of [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)? There are several easy ways to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function of PHP as

```
$result_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);
print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for this case:

```
$data = array( 
        0 => array( "id" => 2, "status" => 1), 
        1 => array( "name" => "you", "class" => "expert"),
        );
$result = array_merge($data[0], $data[1]);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [status] => 1
    [name] => you
    [class] => expert
)
```